# VMWare - Windows Update restarts host, guests lose data. Solutions?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

They didn't like my question on Server Fault, so I'm asking here.

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate as both the host and the guest under VMWare workstation 11. I try to keep both host and guest running all the time, though this is not a production system.

On the host, Windows update installs updates automatically and occasionally wants to restart the host PC automatically in order to complete the process. Personally I think this is a good thing and I'd like to keep it.

The biggest problem I have with this is not that the Guest OS is terminated, but the latest state of the guest does not get saved when this happens. I would like some work around for this so that the host OS can still restart itself automatically.

The ideal solution would be a way to set VMWare to save its state when the host computer is restarting. Is this possible?

Comment: is this what you had in mind? http://csi-windows.com/toolkit/csi-vmwsautoshutdown

Comment: In VMware Workstation 12, running VMs should automatically be suspended if the host shuts down.

Comment: @jamesdlin key word is "should"...I run Workstation 12 and previous versions down to 7 and it has never automatically suspended. Windows updates kill running VMs every time and occasionally I get lost data.

Comment: @guru_florida Suspending VMs on host shutdown is enabled by default in Workstation 12.  if it's not working for you, then it's a bug.